# Installation or cloning Windows 10 on mSATA SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, clone, disk-cloning, msata

I have a laptop with 500gb HDD with Windows 10 in it and I have a free mSATA slot.

I want to keep my files in HDD and install or clone windows in that 128 GB mSATA. So can I clone or copy Windows 10 from HDD to mSATA SSD or will I have to reinstall on the MSATA?

I am afraid that would the BIOS would boot from that mSATA SSD and I would prefer cloning rather than installing.

So basically my main purpose is to keep all my installed app and stuff in Windows hence feel cloning is better. Is this possible, and if so how?

My laptop specs:

- Dell e7440
- i7-4600u
- 4gb DDR3 1600mhz RAM
- 500gb Hynix HDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reinstall Windows using a [Windows installation medium](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) and that will work and will let you keep personal files but will not let you keep all of your programs (which you can just reinstall afterwards).

If you want to keep installed programs, you will first have to move enough of them out of your 500 GB hard drive to a backup drive to get the total size of the installation below 128 GB, then open:

1. Control Panel
2. Backup and Restore (Windows 7)
3. Create a System Image

Store the image somewhere you will be able to access from a Windows installation medium created using the link above, and use the "System Image Recovery Tool" to restore from the created image. Any files and programs moved off the Windows installation can then be moved back onto or reinstalled to the SSD and HDD.

Comment: thanks @Fergus ...My C: partition is of 105 GB and 30 GB is still left. so still i have to clean programs and stuff out of my C drive can i just replicate/clone my full partition onto SSD and one more thing will bios recognize MSATA(i.e. will it boot from it )

Comment: i am actually doing all this because in bios diagnostics SMART reported that my HDD life is over and popped some error .. though it is working fine now and i feel some strange noises and lags too.

Comment: Trusting your SMART report is the safest approach, data loss happens suddenly and is irreparable so it's not worth trusting an old hard drive at end of life. Creating a system image can be pretty harsh on a drive as you put the drive through a lot of read cycles. In case it suddenly dies or writes corrupted data to image I would recommend backing up your most important files manually first to minimise the chance you lose them. Anything not backed up may be lost if it fails.

Comment: As long as a drive (mSATA or otherwise) is plugged in and can be read by the bios, it will be able to be booted from when a boot partition is added. Either approach mentioned in the answer does this. If you are doing a fresh reinstall then Windows will do all the partition management for you, but if you are installing from a system image you may have to reduce the size of the partitions so that they only occupy the first 128 GB of space on your HDD to fit on your smaller drive before making the image. I have shrunk a partition though so I can not make a recommendation on which tools to use.

Comment: thanks so much @Fergus :)

Comment: does system image option copy programs installed??

Comment: i am thinking that i should first  put that ssd in my laptop then go in windows and in c drive i copy/cut all and paste in msata ssd then boot from it

Comment: Yes the system image creates an exact copy of your drive and everything in it, programs and files included. Copying and pasting everything from your C drive in windows explorer won't work, there are boot and recovery partitions and the BIOS needs to be pointed to the correct drive to boot from. Either of the two methods I described do these automatically for you and let Windows take care of it's own issues. Apologies for the late reply, I missed your messages, and no worries at all!

Comment: thanks u are a saviour .. i am texting from phone my hdd died yesterday.. my hdd died yesterday .. now i have to reinstall

Comment: Damn, I hope you managed to save everything important before it happened. Hopefully this will be the end of your troubles when you get reinstalled.

Comment: nah .. i had to go to a hdd file recovery shop .. but now i have msata

Comment: Grand, glad you got sorted. You can mark my answer as accepted with the tick under the voting icons if it answered your question, or you can answer the question yourself and accept it if you feel there was more to it. This way the next person who comes along to the question will be able to see there is an answer that will help them.